# If $u,v$ are orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $||u|| = 3||v||$, then the set $\{u+3v,u-3v\}$ is also orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I can come up with examples where this is true, but I am having trouble generating a formal proof for this. Tried to prove this false with a counter-example but soon realized that wasn't gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

By properties of the dot product, $(u+3v)\cdot(u-3v)=u\cdot u-9v\cdot v - 3u\cdot v+3v\cdot u$.

Now $u\cdot u - 9v\cdot v=|u|^2-|3v|^2=0$ because $|u|=|3v|$,

and $u\cdot v=v\cdot u=0$ because $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal.

Therefore $(u+3v)\cdot(u-3v)=0$; i.e., $u+3v$ and $u-3v$ are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the inner product $<u + 3v, u - 3v>$. Then,

$$<u + 3v, u - 3v> = <u, u> - <u, 3v> + <3v, u> - <3v, 3v>$$

However, $<u, u> = <3v, 3v>$ since :

$$||u|| = 3||v|| \implies ||u||^2 = 9||v||^2 \implies <u, u> = <3v, 3v>$$

Also, $<u, 3v> = 3<u, v> = 3<\overline{v, u}> = 3<v, u> = <3v, u>$.

Thus, $<u + 3v, u - 3v> = 0$